# Get the size of a layout cell of QVBoxLayout in Qt4

Tags: c++, qt4

I am trying to render an image at the appropriate size inside a `QVBoxLayout`, but I am unable to retrieve the correct size. The layout contains a `QLabel`, which is displayed at a good size within the designer view (see image). The goal is to display an image at the maximal available size.

[image: Layout]

Here are my attempts to get the size (all failed):

```
VideoResourceWidget::VideoResourceWidget(VideoResource* resource, QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        ui(new Ui::VideoResourceForm),
        m_videoResource(resource)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // INFO: -> size = (670,463) // this seems to be too small
    m_videoSize = this->geometry().size();

    // first attempt -> size = (0,0)
    m_videoSize = this->geometry().size();
    m_videoSize.setHeight(m_videoSize.height() - ui->controllerLayout->geometry().height());

    // second attempt -> size = (100,30) way too small
    m_videoSize = ui->videoLayout->itemAt(ui->videoLayout->indexOf(ui->frameLabel))->geometry().size();

    ui->videoLayout->activate(); // hint from another question

    // forth attempt -> size = (145,428) better but not still too small
    m_videoSize = ui->videoLayout->itemAt(ui->videoLayout->indexOf(ui->frameLabel))->geometry().size();

    // third attempt -> size = (670,434) there is still a lot more room
    m_videoSize = this->geometry().size();
    m_videoSize.setHeight(m_videoSize.height() - ui->controllerLayout->geometry().height());

    ui->videoLayout->setSpacing(1);
    ui->frameLabel->setMargin(0);

    ui->videoLayout->activate(); // hint from another question

    // fifth attempt -> size = (145,428) same as before
    m_videoSize = ui->videoLayout->itemAt(ui->videoLayout->indexOf(ui->frameLabel))->geometry().size();

    // sixth attempt -> size = (670,434) same as before
    m_videoSize = this->geometry().size();
    m_videoSize.setHeight(m_videoSize.height() - ui->controllerLayout->geometry().height());

    QImage frame = m_videoResource->firstFrame();
    ui->frameLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(frame).scaled(m_videoSize, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));

    connect(ui->nextFrameButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(nextFrame()));
}
```

This is the GUI after displaying the `VideoResourceWidget` for the first time.

[image: Displaying the first frame]

While the end result does not have to be pretty, I would love to use the available space effectively.

**Update:** I updated the screen shots to reflect my latest attempts.

**Update:** minimal example:

mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>771</width>
    <height>580</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout" stretch="1,0">
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="displayLayout" stretch="0,0,0">
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
    <property name="orientation">
     <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
     <size>
      <width>40</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </size>
    </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="frameLabel">
    <property name="text">
     <string>TextLabel</string>
    </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
    <property name="orientation">
     <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
     <size>
      <width>40</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </size>
    </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="controllerLayout" stretch="1,0">
      <item>
       <widget class="QScrollBar" name="horizontalScrollBar">
    <property name="orientation">
     <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
    </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="nextButton">
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>771</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void next();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QSize m_imageSize;
    QImage m_image;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->layout()->activate();

    connect(ui->nextButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(next()));

    // Goal: display the image centered using the maximally available space
    m_image = QImage("/tmp/lena.jpg");
    m_imageSize = ui->frameLabel->size();
    ui->frameLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(m_image).scaled(m_imageSize, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::next()
{
    // just redraw
    m_imageSize = ui->frameLabel->size();
    ui->frameLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(m_image).scaled(m_imageSize, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
}
```

Comment: 1) if the label is too small try out setting sizeHint to expand and try out setting all margins and spacings in all involved layouts. It's gotta there. 2) construct a minimal example that I can run myself, and I provide the correct answer (hopefully).

Comment: First of all, thank you for your efforts. I am currently busy preparing something unrelated and have not had the time to create a minimal example. I'll get back to you once I can focus on this again.

Answer (score 1):

Decrease the size of the margins and spacing (play with it. I am not sure which is what) of your layouts. This way the label gets more space, and so does your picture.

I am not sure what you expect it to look like, but the second screen shot looks very good to me. (keep aspect ration makes it take the height of the label). It's just not centered.

- [spacing](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlayout.html#spacing-prop)
- [margin](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to remove the spacers, first.  Then set the Label's sizeHint (as somebody else already pointed out).

If you really need the spacers in Place, set their stretchFactors to "0", and the stretchFactor of the Label to "1".

Actually I wouldn't use a QLabel to render a video, but I guess this is just a test, and I know QLabel is easy to use for displaying pixmaps.  My choice would be to go for performance and reimplement QGLWidget and do the video-render via OpenGL.